# Error:String types not allowed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android.
I am facing the following error:
**String types not allowed**

> **EDIT**: I have kept the image.jpg in **Resources -> drawwble- hdpi**

Refer the code below:
**Strings.xml**

```
 <drawable name="test_image">image.jpg</drawable>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/desc" 
android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
```

**Android_manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: to know about string resources check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html. To just set image to a imageview follow the answer by Ahmad

Comment: you need to provide access permission in `manifest.xml`. try googling out for that.

Comment: Its a compile time bug. Has it anything to do with `target SDK` ?

Comment: When you use @drawable/<filename>, it refers to the file <filename> with extension jpg or png or gif that you placed in the drawable folder. So, if your image is called image.jpg, you should use @drawable/image, or you should rename your image to test_image.jpg.

Comment: please would you check again if the name of the image includes any capital letter

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: No Caps. the name is `image.jpg`

Comment: refresh your project, put `android:src="@drawable/image"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/test_image"`then save your layout

Comment: SOlved !!! You should not put <drawable ...> into the file String.xml. You should put your image file (which should be a jpg or a gif or a png) into the subdirectory res/drawable of your project. Then you reference that image in the xml file with @drawable/<filename>, where <filename> is the name of the image you placed in the drawable folder, without extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Place your image in `res/drawable` folder.
2. also remove the file extension.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/desc" 
android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

`@drawable/image` represents your drawable named "image".

Comment: Whats the difference between `android:src="@drawable/image"` AND `android:src="@drawable/test_image"` when both `image` & `test_image` refer to the same resource ?

Comment: SOlved !!! **You should not put <drawable ...> into the file String.xml.** You should put your image file (which should be a jpg or a gif or a png) into the subdirectory res/drawable of your project. Then you reference that image in the xml file with @drawable/<filename>, where <filename> is the name of the image you placed in the drawable folder, without extension

Answer (score 2):

The value of the attribute android:src should be a drawable object. So you should put the file 'image.jpg' into the folder res/drawable/ of your Android project, and then replace the line:

```
android:src="@drawable/test_image"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

that will reference the file 'image.jpg' that you placed in the drawable folder.

Comment: Tried that. But still the error is same. Are you sure we write like this only in String.xml : `<drawable name="test_image">image.jpg</drawable>` OR `<drawable name="test_image">image</drawable>`

But the error states: **String types not allowed**

Comment: You should not put <drawable ...> into the file String.xml. You should put your image file (which should be a jpg or a gif or a png) into the subdirectory res/drawable of your project. Then you reference that image in the xml file with @drawable/<filename>, where <filename> is the name of the image you placed in the drawable folder, without extension.